# Loop array php (foreach)

Tags: php

Hi guys please i have a question , i have an array with 250 value i want to output all these value like this

```
foreach($myArray as $x => $x_value) {
     $pic = strtolower($x);

     // here i want to echo only 83 value like this 
     // <td>83 value</td> <td>83 value</td> <td>83 value</td>

     echo "<img src='http://<my website>/$pic.png'/>$x_value";
     echo "<br>";
}
```

guys this my array

```
    $countries = array
    (
        'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
        'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
        'AL' => 'Albania',
        // 250 country
    );

// 83 country in each colmun
// i want to echo <td> 83 country here </td> and <td> 83 country here </td> and <td> 83 country here </td>
```

i'm sorry about my english i'm trying to do my best to make it easy for you to undrestand what i want.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: i want to output these value like this : <td>83 value</td> <td>83 value</td> <td>83 value</td>

Comment: show some part of your `$myArray` to recognize the intended content

Comment: yeh exactly in other words 250/3

Comment: what is `83` number in your case? it's not an array key nor value

Comment: inside my array there is 250 country names i want to split them to 3 column
$countries = array
(
    'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
    'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
    'AL' => 'Albania',
// all country names
);

Answer (score 1):

You can make a own counter if you don't use the for() loop like this;

```
// Array for counting total and 83
$count = array(
    "count" => 0, 
    "countNew" => 0
);

echo "<td>"; //Start with opening a <td>
foreach($myArray as $x => $x_value) {
    $count["count"]++; // Keep counting till end of array
    $count["countNew"]++; // Count for 250 / 3

    $pic = strtolower($x);

    // Get interval arraylengt / 3
    $tdThis = intval(floor(count($myArray) / 3));

    echo $x_value;
    if($count["countNew"] >= $tdThis){

        // Whenever we reach the 83 reset to 0 for new count to 83
        $count["countNew"] = 0;
        // Close </td> on every 83 countries
        echo "</td>";

        // If we don't reach the array end add new td 
        if($count["count"] === count($myArray)){
            echo "<td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SaSuki, If i'm understand it, you want to start the `<td>` echo out `83` land values and close `</td>` than re-open `<td>` and so on... ? I

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($myArray as $x => $x_value) {
 $pic = strtolower($x);
 // here i want to echo only 83 value like this 
 // <td>83 value</td> <td>83 value</td> <td>83 value</td>

 if($x==83)
    echo "<td>$x</td> <td>$x_value</td>";

 echo "<img src='http://<my website>/$pic.png'/>$x_value";
 echo "<br>";
```

}